# How to find the 95% upper limit for theta?

Tags: confidence-interval

**Problem + Attempt**

I need to construct an upper 95% confidence limit $q_r$ for $\theta$. From the theory I understand that probability that the true value is smaller than $q_r$ is 95%. It is given in the problem statement that $\frac{\widehat{\theta}_{M L}}{\theta}$ is a pivotal quantity. It is also given that $\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\hat{\theta}_{M L}}{\theta} \leq x\right)$ = $x^{4 n}$.

From a similar problem I know I can write

- $\mathbb{P}( q_l< \frac{\widehat{\theta}_{M L}}{\theta} < q_r) = 1 - \alpha = 0.95 $.

Since this problem only requires the upper limit I can rewrite the expression as:

- $\mathbb{P}(\frac{\widehat{\theta}_{M L}}{\theta} < q_{0.95}) = 1 - \alpha = 0.95 $

This quantile $q_{95}$ is to be calculated with the use of the CDF given. Since I can make use of the following property:

$F_X(x)=\mathrm{P}(X \leq x)$

The equation looks like:

$0.95 = (q_{0.95})^{4 n}$

$(0.95)^\frac{1}{4n} = q_{0.95}$

With the value for $q_{0.95}$ known, I rewrite this expression:

$\mathbb{P}(\theta < \frac{\widehat{\theta}_{M L}}{(0.95)^\frac{1}{4n}}) $

Unfortunately this is the wrong solution according to the manual:

> The upper one-sided $95 \%$ confidence limit is thus
> $\frac{\widehat{\theta}_{M L}}{(0.05)^{1 / 4n}}$

**Question**

- What is wrong with the above described logic?

The official answer makes sense, since the numerical value is simply larger. There is probably an ugly flaw in my logic described above. I hope that I could get feedback on this

Comment: How did you "rewrite" the expression?  It looks like you reversed the inequality.

Comment: @whuber thanks for the reply! Honestly I don't see what is wrong. Could you please indicate what is wrong?

Comment: Your algebra is incorrect.  The rewritten expression should have "$\gt$" rather than "$\lt$".